# How can do conditional statement to set data value to zero when fetch data not avaliable from database by laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

i have one problem , i try to fetch data from database to show it on view page ..

when this data not ready in database , i dont want to show

```
attempt to read property on null or 404 not found
```

its migration table is as follow

```
Schema::create('prices', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('openprice')->nullable();
            $table->string('closeprice')->nullable();
            $table->string('highprice')->nullable();
            $table->string('lowprice')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

my fetch code is

```
        $now = CarbonImmutable::now();
        
        $MinuteAgo = $now->subMinute(70);
   
 
        $pricelist = Sell::whereBetween('created_at', [$MinuteAgo,$now])->orderBy('id','asc')->get();
        $priceHL = Sell::whereBetween('created_at', [$MinuteAgo,$now])->orderBy('price','asc')->get();


            $openprice = $pricelist->first()->price;
            $closeprice = $pricelist->last()->price;
            $highprice = $priceHL->last()->price;
            $lowprice = $priceHL->first()->price;
```

if data not ready in database , it get problem in view ,

i just want to show in view when data not ready , its value as zero ,

example ,

```
if data ready , $openprice = 0.0011 
if not ready , $openprice = 0
```

how can do it , can it be or not , i have low experience in data manipulation ,

my target achivement is  not to distrub to view page , when no data , this will show error page .

```
Route::get('/candle',[App\Http\Controllers\ChartController::class, 'chart']);
```

if so , user interface will get trouble for users.

actually i try is to show candlestick chart on this view page , so if some minutes interval data not ready , the candle chart page will get error in display .

can someone help me .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your data based on `$pricelist` so

```
if ($pricelist->isEmpty()) {
    $openprice = 0;
    $closeprice = 0;
    $highprice = 0;
    $lowprice = 0;
} else {
    $openprice = $pricelist->first()->price;
    $closeprice = $pricelist->last()->price;
    $highprice = $priceHL->last()->price;
    $lowprice = $priceHL->first()->price;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use folelse loop

```
 @forelse($data as $datum) 
    your data to display / code 
 @empty 
    <div> No data exits </div>
 @endforelse
```